# how to unzip a zipped file in s3

Tags: python, boto3, unzip, zip

I have a zipped file in a folder in a s3 bucket. I want to unzip the file using boto3. This is my code so far.

```
def unzip_file(path, file_name):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)

    lst = list(my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path))
    unzip_path = '/'.join(str(lst[0].key).split('/')[:-1])

    with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{path}/{file_name}", 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(unzip_path)
```

But this just gives an error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 153, in <module>
    unzip_file(path, file_name)
  File "download.py", line 32, in unzip_file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{path}/{file_name}", 'r') as zip_ref:
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1250, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_parent/test_num/test.zip'
```

How do I unzip the file with python and boto3?

## [EDIT1]

I have edited the code such that the zipped file is now in memory. How do I extract all the files into S3.

this is my code now

```
def unzip_file(r, path, file_name):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        filebytes = BytesIO(r.content)
        file = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)

        extract_folder = f"{path}extract_test/"
        
        # extract each file in file.namelist() and save in extract_folder here
```

Comment: Did you download that file? Seems you did not.

Comment: @Marcin is it necessary to download the file to my local system? I can view the zipped file in the AWS portal. can't I run the code to unzip on the the S3 bucket itself?

Comment: No you can't , because S3 is not a filesystem, but an object store. You have to dowload the file first, to local hdd or memory.

Comment: @Marcin I have edited the code to keep the zipped file in memory. How do I extract the files now?

Comment: look at .put_object(Body=obj, Bucket=my_bucket, Key=key). this deals with objects in memory rather than upload_file(). You may have to play around with the Body to be sure you are uploading correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not sure what `r.content` is and the logic behind your function, I provide a **working example**:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

import boto3

BUCKET='my-bucket'
key='my.zip'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)

# mem buffer
filebytes = BytesIO()

# download to the mem buffer
my_bucket.download_fileobj(key, filebytes)

# create zipfile obj
file = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)

# extact
file.extractall('/tmp/extract_test')
```

Comment: This will be unzipping the files into `/tmp/extract_test` in the local system. How do I extract it directly in the s3 bucket?

Comment: @Sashaank Simillarly. You have to unzip it locally, and then upload each unzipped file to S3.

Comment: @Sashaank If you are on linux, you can mimic S3 being a filesystem using https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse . This can simply the downloads and uploads.

Answer (score 1):

The `/tmp` folder mentioned in the answer above might work but the folder has a limited memory and in case of larger zipped files, your function might not work correctly. You can do something like this:

```
        zipped_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=sourcebucketname, key=filekey)
        buffer = BytesIO(zipped_file.get()["Body"].read())
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
        
        for file in zipped.namelist():
            logger.info(f'current file in zipfile: {file}')
            final_file_path = file + '.file_extension'

            with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
                content = f_in.read()
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

Once unzipped, you can either upload back to another S3 folder or to some local folder. Here's a full working code: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9